# Is concept of Weak and Strong Field Ligands applicable in Valence Bond Theory?

Tags: coordination-compounds, valence-bond-theory, crystal-field-theory

I am high school student studying Coordination- Chemistry. I have read about Valence bond theory and Crystal Field Theory as well.

My teacher taught me that Valence bond theory is based on experimental value of magnetic moment whereas CFT focuses on splitting of orbitals in presence of Weak and Strong Field Ligands. My confusion is that can we explain VBT configuration on basis of SFL and WFL?

Like in one of my theory exams, we were asked to write configuration of [Fe(NH3)6]3+ **on basis of VBT**. But no magnetic moment data was given in question. Then how should I have written the configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah buddy I think you were thinking correctly, since NH3 is strong field ligand it will cause pairing, there are 5 electrons in 3d orbital of fe(3+) so there will be two pairs and one lone pair (you can find B.M using (n(n+1))^1/2 ) also since 2 d orbitals are vacant along with one s and three p hybridization will be sp3d2 ie octahedral. But one point remains VBT doesn't consider SFT or WFT as per my memory, and it's also counted as it's limitations. But generally this way is used to solve exam questions.